# URI Online Judge Problem Fibonacci Series

Tags: python-3.x, uri, series, fibonacci

problem link: https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1151

why this is not accepted?

```
n=int(input())
x=0
lst=[]

while True:
    
    if int(len(lst)) == 0:
        lst.append('0')
    elif int(len(lst)) == 1:
        lst.append('1')
    
    else:
        x=int(lst[-1])+int(lst[-2])
        if x>=n:
            break
        else:
            lst.append(x)


result=' '.join([str(elem) for elem in lst])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

"print" automatically put "\n" to the end of string. Try use

```
print(result, end="")
```

instead of

```
print(result)
```